# Pass JS function values of multiple input fields after change in one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have HTML form with lots of select and input fields, using it a user selects his order items per each category (items of the same category have the same class). each item also has fields for other properties e.g. quantity, color etc.
here is an example form:

```
<form>
    <!--Category: Cats-->
    <label>Cat:</label>
    <select id="cat" class="cats">
        <option>nice</option>
        <option>ugly</option></select>
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cat_qty" class="cats" />
    <br />
    <!--Category: Dogs-->
    <label>Dog:</label>
    <select id="dog" class="dogs">
        <option>nice</option>
        <option>ugly</option></select>
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dog_qty" class="dogs" />
    <br />
</form>
```

The real form has many many more categories. also, because of presentation necessities, there are fields that belong to the same category that i can't group together inside the same parent tag, meaning that they reside in totally different places in the HTML page.

Let us imagine that the user just made a change to one field in the form. I'm searching for the most elegant way to trigger a JS function each time a change happens, and to pass it the values of **all** fields that have the same class of the changed field, so that i can create a JSON string which i'll send using Jquery's .AJAX call in order to update a record in my DB.

For example, if the user choose in 'cat' - 'ugly', a JS function will be called that can create the variable:

```
fields = {  "cat":"ugly",
            "cat_qty" : "6"}
```

and then

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/update.php",
    data: { Myfields: fields },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {}
       });
```

Can you suggest an elegant way? I'm not sure whether to use OnChange calls, the Jquery 'Change' function (either way i didn't find how to do it using them..) OR ANY OTHER WAY :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well 1st you have to give all your input fields names (and the form an ID):

```
<form id='pickAnimal'>
    <!--Category: Cats-->
    <label>Cat:</label>
    <select id="cat" class="cats" name='cat'>
        <option>nice</option>
        <option>ugly</option></select>
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cat_qty" class="cats" name='cat_qty' />
    <br />
    <!--Category: Dogs-->
    <label>Dog:</label>
    <select id="dog" class="dogs" name='dog'>
        <option>nice</option>
        <option>ugly</option></select>
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dog_qty" class="dogs" name='dog_qty'/>
    <br />
</form>
```

and then the js to serialize the choice:

```
$('input, select', $('#pickAnimal')).change(function(){

    var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var theForm = $('#pickAnimal');

    var dataFields = $('.'+theClass, theForm).serialize();
    //gets all data from fields in the form that have the same class

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/update.php",
       data: dataFields,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function() {}
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery change: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Here's how it could be used:

```
$('#cat, #dog').change(function(e) {

    var _this = $(this);
    var value = _this.val();
    var id = _this.attr('id');
    var input = _this.siblings(':input');
    var quantity = input.val();

    var data = {};
    data[id] = value;
    data[input.attr('id')] = quantity;

    // do ajax stuff

});
```

Comment: this is not very expandable at all, and you would have to add a line for every new element in the form...

Comment: I agree. The better solution is to make this generic by giving every element you want to use this code the same class, and change the selector to that class. Also, if his data needs to be formatted a particular way that doesn't match the names of the elements, serialization won't help. But I would argue that the data should be stored with the elements in such a way that they can be easily serialized and have the server expect them in that format.

Comment: @Eli and that is basically what i did in my answer, and that is what the OP has.

Comment: I was giving an example of how to use change, not how to serialize elements.

Comment: a part of the question was about using change, the earlier part was about serializing the vars

Comment: Hmmm... "Can you suggest an elegant way? I'm not sure whether to use OnChange calls, or just the Jquery 'Change' function, and either way i didn't find how to do it using them.." Sounds like the question to me.

Comment: i read this part: `For example, if the user choose in 'cat' - 'ugly', a JS function will be called that can create the variable:` as well as that last part to make my answer ^_^

Comment: Still doesn't sound like a question...he obviously knows how to create data. The question posed was how to use change to get to the element which has the data.

Comment: ok. to each their own, but your answer wont help the OP that much

Comment: Ok, so he asks how to use change and I give an example. How is that not helpful?

Comment: your answer is full of errors. did u try it on jsfiddle? (with more options aside from qty)

Comment: It's an example dude, you can't let go, can you?

Comment: @Eli, yes, but on stack usually you should give working examples ^_^

Comment: @Eli, you dont have to. it was already done ^_^ (sorry im mean)

Comment: Haha, it's ok, I'm used to mean people.

Comment: Hey guys thank you both for your answers, let me chew it a few minutes. BTW what i meant was:
whether to use OnChange calls, the Jquery 'Change' function, OR ANY OTHER WAY. i'll fix it. anyway, no need to argue, peace and love

Comment: LOVE AND LIGHT EVERYONE! rofl. That's what I'm getting at: use jQuery's `change` method.

Comment: @Israel, ddnt mean to argue, just geekyness hehe

Comment: @Eli, i also used the `.change()` method :-p

Comment: I don't have a problem with your implementation. It will work in all situations where the names of the elements are the keys used for submitting. It won't work if that's not the case.

Comment: No one has mentioned light. here in Israel it's already night Eli.